union type data serialization
I'm trying to use ConvertRecord to deserialize a union type of data from avro to json.
However I've seen different behavior
The schema is defined as:
   "name": "data",
                "type": [
                    "null",
                    "bytes"
                ],
                "default": null
            }

However, I'm expecting to see (in nifi 1.8):
"data": {
        "bytes": "####################"

Instead, I get (in nifi 1.23.2)
"data":  "####################"

It seems that the avro deserializer convert union to simple key-value
Is there a way to preserve the original union format for data
